# ARM template for Azure Log Analytics Data Collector

Tags: azure, arm, azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics

I have been trying to create an ARM template for the Log Analytics Data collector API connection. I have almost got the ARM template but I'm unable to find where can I insert the Workspace Key value in the API connection to make it work.

Here is my ARM template for the API connection of Azure Log analytics Data collector.=

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
  },
  "variables": {
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "displayName": "pankajtestlog",
        "statuses": [
          {
            "status": "Connected"
          }
        ],
        "customParameterValues": {},
        "nonSecretParameterValues": {
          "username": "yP4jrRxnB8EfXIO8Y27as+JbDMEUmIOk1K4QB5NuvTei9yELgzdjUCejWmwgb4AVpw81lg0NpOcpvdvmLM/Hqw=="
        },
        "createdTime": "2020-04-11T07:57:31.1911201Z",
        "changedTime": "2020-04-11T07:57:31.1911201Z",
        "api": {
          "name": "azureloganalyticsdatacollector",
          "displayName": "Azure Log Analytics Data Collector",
          "description": "Azure Log Analytics Data Collector will send data to any Azure Log Analytics workspace.",
          "iconUri": "https://connectoricons-prod.azureedge.net/azureloganalyticsdatacollector/icon_1.0.1274.1744.png",
          "brandColor": "#0072C6",
          "category": "Standard",
          "id": "/subscriptions/44357e6b-77a0-4b60-a817-27e62ffb6fdd/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/usgovarizona/managedApis/azureloganalyticsdatacollector",
          "type": "Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis"
        },
        "testLinks": []
      },
      "id": "/subscriptions/44357e6b-77a0-4b60-a817-27e62ffb6fdd/resourceGroups/RG-Guardian-POC/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureloganalyticsdatacollector-1",
      "name": "azureloganalyticsdatacollector-1",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
      "location": "usgovarizona",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01"
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
  }
}
```

If you see the tempalte here the username parameter under nonSecretParameterValues is the Workspace ID but I'm unable to find what is the property to be added for Workspace shared key. The below screenshot would be helpful. Can someone help me add that property or you have any ARM for this. I have got this template from the ARMClient Tool.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the log analytics workspace share key in the arm template, you can use the ARM template function `listKeys` to get it. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#implementations)

The expression should be like

```
listKeys(resourceId('<group name>','Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces', '<space name>'), providers('Microsoft.OperationalInsights', 'workspaces').apiVersions[0]).primarySharedKey]
```

For example

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "location":{
        "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"


    },
    "azureloganalyticsdatacollector_1_Connection_Name": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "azureloganalyticsdatacollector"
    },
    "azureloganalyticsdatacollector_1_Connection_DisplayName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "test2"
    },
    "azureloganalyticsdatacollector_1_username": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue":"fcbee0dd-1bb6-4c2b-a522-ea90b8606752",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The unique identifier of the Azure Log Analytics workspace."
      },

    },
    "azureloganalyticsdatacollector_1_password": {
      "type": "securestring",
       "defaultValue":"5SFB4B54oiTKBZDcJrBgMw8c81hEaW7rYtC2A9wLh4/eATEOI4XxvGBVOor/ulmYRJePr3VqxACjBk7fvCpWbQ==",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The primary or secondary key of the Azure Log Analytics workspace."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
 {
      "type": "MICROSOFT.WEB/CONNECTIONS",
      "apiVersion": "2018-07-01-preview",
      "name": "[parameters('azureloganalyticsdatacollector_1_Connection_Name')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "api": {
          "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('location'), '/managedApis/', 'azureloganalyticsdatacollector')]"
        },
        "displayName": "[parameters('azureloganalyticsdatacollector_1_Connection_DisplayName')]",
        "parameterValues": {
          "username": "[parameters('azureloganalyticsdatacollector_1_username')]",
          "password": "[listKeys(resourceId('defaultresourcegroup-se','Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces', 'DefaultWorkspace-e5b0fcfa-e859-43f3-8d84-5e5fe29f4c68-SE'), providers('Microsoft.OperationalInsights', 'workspaces').apiVersions[0]).primarySharedKey]"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {

  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help Jim. It was helpful and solved my problem.

Comment: Hi @JimXu, I need one more help related to ARM Template. 
When I try to create a SQL Connection via Azure Active directory it doesn't work. Currenly I have an Azure ARM template which deploys A SQL API connection but with SQL AUthentication I need it with AD Authentication.Can you help me out with that.

Answer (score 1):

You need the primary/secondary key of the log analytics workspace you have created. This can be found `Advanced Settings` blade of your workspace if you want a portal experience or can be found using the AZ CLI.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my scenario was not how to get the value. but to get the property is used to be used in ARM tempate for shared key so that the ARM deployment of API connection is successful. Thanks again. I was able to solve this.